# How to validate JQuery forms that have multiple name[] arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

These fields are created with JQuery.

How do I validate the array of "aname[]" fields (you have to fill them in before going to the next step)?

JQuery to HTML:

```
input ="<input  name='aname[]' id='1' placeholder='yourname1'  type='text' required />";
input +="<input  name='aname[]' id='2' placeholder='yourname2'  type='text' required />";
input +="<input  name='aname[]' id='3' placeholder='yourname3'  type='text' required />";
$(".placeholder").append(input);
```

JQuery command to try and get input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $('input[name="items[]"]').text();
    if(items == ""){
        alert("fill this field");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `text()` retrieves the text of an element (like a `span` or `div`), not the value of an input. To get the value of an input, use `val`. (Or if just working with the DOM element, the `value` property.)
2. You need to run the check in response to an event, not just on page load.
3. If you change `text()` to `val()` in that code, you'll only be checking the value of the **first** one (`text()` is a bit odd and works differently to `val()` and most other jQuery getters).

So if you want to check that *all* of them are filled in, you'll need an event handler and a loop of some kind:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("selector-for-the-form").on("submit", function(e) {
        $(this).find('input[name="items[]"]').each(function() {
            if (this.value == "") {
                this.focus();             // So the user knows which field...
                alert("fill this field"); // ...although this may mess that up
                e.preventDefault();       // Prevent form submission
                return false;             // Stop looping
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Of course, `alert` isn't usually the greatest user experience for this sort of thing. It's usually more pleasant if you do proactive validation and a notification that doesn't jar the user and interrupt what they're doing until you have to (like changing the color of the border of the input and/or showing an inline message). (There are also lots of plugins available to help you with doing that.)

Comment: I just used alert() for tests.  Most of the time I use toastr.  I was wondering about if I should use .each, but wasn't sure how until your explanation. Great info :)

Comment: Would we need to do an e.preventDefault(); ?  This would stop the form submit.

Comment: @user7480839: Doh! Yes. That's why I declared the `e` param, but I forgot to add the call! I've added it now, along with a `return false;` in the `each` to stop looping when we find the first problematic field. (Which you may or may not want if using toastr.)